# Mysql multiple modifications on same column in one alter query

Tags: php, mysql

I have a php script that compares table differences anad returns an alter query.This alter query has multiple modifications on same column.But when I execute this query it throws an error stating unknown column.
my query is as follows:

```
ALTER TABLE `databasename`.`tablename`  
MODIFY `msgid` int(11)  NOT NULL,
MODIFY COLUMN `msgid` int(11) DEFAULT '0';
```

As you can see above msgid is being modified twice in the same query.I need to know why mysql wont acept this query.

Comment: What has php got to do with this apart from the fact that you are using the results somewhere that isn't even shown? Are you sure the column `msgid` exists in the table `databasename.tablename`? Because MySQL doesn't think so

Comment: column msgid does exist in the table

Comment: Just simply use   ALTER TABLE `databasename`.`tablename`  
MODIFY `msgid` int(11)  NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/alter-table.html "Multiple ADD, ALTER, DROP, and CHANGE clauses are permitted in a single ALTER TABLE statement, separated by commas" MODIFY clause can't be used multiple times within a ALTER table statement.

Answer (score 0):

Should be:

```
ALTER TABLE `databasename`.`tablename`  
MODIFY `msgid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0';
```

*Edit:* 
This is as Sunil Pachlangia says in the comments